# Swiper.IO pagination dots now showing

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, swiper.js

for some reason the swiper does not show the pagination for the image casousel that i crated. 
It shows up in the dom but with the height of 0. Changing it manually did not do anything. Any ideas?

```
import Swiper from '../../vendor/swiper.min.js';

export default {
  name: 'ImageCarouselBlock',
  components: {
    MediaImage,
  },
  props: {
    cmsData: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    let carouselConfig = {};
    if (this.cmsData.auto){
      carouselConfig = {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlide: true,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 2000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
      };
    }
    else {
      carouselConfig = {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
      };
    }
    const mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', carouselConfig);
  },
  computed: {
    images() {
      return this.cmsData.images.map( image => {
        return {
          //  TODO maybe get something from amplicence that tells how big they want the carousel to be?
          imageData : getMediaAndSources(image.name, '1500'),
        };
      });
    },
  },
};
```

And this is the corresponding template. I tried changing the position of where i put the pagination element but nothing worked. I am out of ideas here and i need some help.

```
<div class="image-carousel-block">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="image in images">
        <media-image preload="true" :sources="image.imageData.sources" :media="image.imageData.media" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working Example of your above code in snippet Please

Comment: Obviously when trying it out in a jsfiddle with some few changes to make it work to my surprise it actually worked. No idea what could be wrong with my project @Awais

Comment: Then i am sure the issue is with your import `import Swiper from '../../vendor/swiper.min.js';` may be your url is not correct. Please double check the path of `swiper.min.js`

Comment: I also thought so, but i checked it is correct. Would the swiper work as intended even if the path to the js file is bad? @Awais

Comment: No if the path of js in not correct it fails to perform any action. Did you import thier Css as well? like mention here https://swiperjs.com/get-started/. I think styles `swiper.min.css` are missing thats why dots not shown

Comment: @Awais we were on the right path, check the edit. Thanks for helping out

Comment: Glad that works. now post it as an answer, remove that solution form question so that it helps other

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was in my vue file.

```
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<style lang="stylus" scoped> -- wrong here
  @import '../../vendor/swiper.styl'
  @import './style.styl'
</style>
```

Removing "scoped" did the trick for me.